# How to change DML link color in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

I am using WinDbg 6.3.9600.16384 from the Windows 8.1 SDK. I prefer a dark background, but it makes the dark blue DML links difficult to read. I've been through the list of color changing options in View->Options, but none of them seem to alter the link color.

Does anybody know how to change the color of DML links in WinDbg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DML color itself cannot be changed, but it will turn to white if you set the background to black. So, if you can live with a black background ("Normal level command window text background"), it works fine.

[image: Screenshot of WinDbg with different background colors]